# Accidentally did git push instead of git push -u origin <branch>

Tags: git

On a branch, I did several commits followed by `git push` when I should have been doing `git push -u origin mybranch`. Fortunately a colleague noticed via `git log` that my changes weren't there before we spent hours assuming they were (since everything looks good from my machine)... is there any way to fix this retroactively?

Comment: You can still do a `git push -u origin mybranch` to get your commits to the proper upstream repository. Or did I miss something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't remember what message I received after trying `git push -u origin mybranch`, but that's all I had to do